# Transform properties from JSON array into comma-separated string

Tags: sql, json, azure, sql-server-2012

I have a string column in an SQL-Server table on Azure which contains the following data:

```
 {
        "status": "success",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Jane",
                "type": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "John",
                "type": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can it be transformed into a comma-separated string containing `"Jane, John"`?

Comment: Is `"data"` always going to be the same size? For example will it always be two items or do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: Hi, "data" has no constant size, it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to achieve this via a snippet of some of my older code, you should be able to loop through the table and do this for each row. There may be a quicker way of doing it but this will work.

```sql
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(200) = '{"status": "success", "data": [{"name": "Jane", "type": 0},{"name": "John", "type": 0}]}',
    @result nvarchar(max) = ''


SELECT @result = @result + [value] + N', '
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT data.value
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.data') as jsondata
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata.value) as data
    WHERE data.[key] = 'name') a

select @result = substring(@result, 1, (LEN(@result)-1))

select @result
```